# unknown attribute 'gradework' for Feedback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following error:

> "tribute 'gradework' for Feedback."

In the link is the screen of the rails console and the parameters that are sent are:

```
"{" feedback "=> {" anotations "=>" Holiiii "," score "=>" 12 " 1 "," user "=>" # <User: 0x007f4674123f38> "}}"
```

Error Image:

[image: Error Image]

feedback.rb

```
class CreateFeedbacks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
   def change
     create_table :feedbacks do |t|
       t.text :anotations
       t.integer :score
       t.references :gradework, foreign_key: true
       t.references :user, foreign_key: true
       t.timestamps
     end
   end
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "feedbacks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "anotations"
    t.integer  "score"
    t.integer  "gradework_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.index ["gradework_id"], name: "index_feedbacks_on_gradework_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_feedbacks_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

create_table "gradeworks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "status"
    t.date     "delivery_date"
    t.date     "begin_date"
    t.time     "hour"
    t.text     "locale"
    t.string   "semester"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.string   "file"
  end
```

feedbackController:

```
def create
     @feedback = Feedback.new(feedback_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @feedback.save!
        format.html { redirect_to @feedback, notice: 'Feedback was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @feedback }
      else
        format.html { render :new, notice: 'Feedback was not created.' }
        format.json { render json: @feedback.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end   

def feedback_params
      params.require(:feedback).permit(:anotations, :score, :gradework, :user)
    end
```

view:

```
<form role="form" id="newForm" action="/feedbacks" method="post">

      <div class="form-group">        
          Comentario:<br>
          <textarea  type="text" rows="5" class="form-control"
             id="inputAnotations" placeholder="Ingrese su comentario"                                                    name="feedback[anotations]" required></textarea>
        <br><br>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
                Score:<br>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="feedback[score]">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gradework">Tesis:</label>
             <%= select_tag(:gradework, options_from_collection_for_select(@grad_jury ,:id, :name), :prompt => "Ninguno", class: "form-control", name: "feedback[gradework]") %>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
            <%#User:<br>%>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="feedback[user]" value= <%= @cUser %>>
    </div>

      <br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="">Agregar</button>
    <!-- <input type="submit" value="Agregar"> -->
</form>
```

I do not know what's wrong!

Comment: Try setting `gradework` instead of `gradework_id` in your view. Can you share your view (`new.html.erb`)?

Comment: Now add the view and this is the query 
" def self.users_gradework(id)
joins(:users).select("gradeworks.id,gradeworks.name,gradeworks.description")
.where({ users: { id: id } })
  end"

Comment: The relation is  " has_and_belongs_to_many :gradeworks"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be here:

```
<%= select_tag(:gradework, options_from_collection_for_select(@grad_jury ,:id, :name), :prompt => "Ninguno", class: "form-control", name: "feedback[gradework]") %>
```

Your form is sending a `gradework` attribute that is not in your model (`Feedback`), so you need to send `gradework_id` instead, so try chaning the above line to this:

```
<%= select_tag(:gradework_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@grad_jury ,:id, :name), :prompt => "Ninguno", class: "form-control", name: "feedback[gradework_id]") %>
```

That will send `gradework_id` as a parameter with whatever value is chosen in the `select`.

Comment: Change gradework by gradework_id but still the error continues.

Comment: @SebastianMoralesGarzón In your error screen, what are you getting now on **Parameters:**?

Comment: If it was that along with one more detail, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to have 2 two things to create gradework entry along with feedback entry from your view:

1. `belongs_to :gradework` in `Feedback` model.
2. The name in the form should be `feedback[gradework_attributes]` instead of `feedback[gradework]`

Comment: When I change the relation I got the following error  "Gradework(#69970235955560) expected, got String(#15868000)".